# AWS - boto3 EC2 start/stop - automation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I prepared lambda function, I am using python boto3 module, code below. Now I am facing error message `"errorMessage": "start_instances() only accepts keyword arguments."`. What could be the problem, I was using this automation, and for two weeks I am facing this error.

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    ec2_regions = [region['RegionName'] for region in client.describe_regions()['Regions']]
    for region in ec2_regions:
        ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name=region)
        instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['stopped']}])
        StoppedInstances = [instance.id for instance in instances]
        for i in StoppedInstances:
            startingInstances = ec2.instances.start(i)
            print(startingInstances)
            print(ec2_regions)
```

Updated version

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    #region = 'eu-west-1'
    ec2_regions = [region['RegionName'] for region in client.describe_regions()['Regions']]
    for region in ec2_regions:
        ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name=region)
        instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['stopped']}])
        StoppedInstances = [instance.id for instance in instances]
        print(StoppedInstances)
        print(ec2_regions)
        client.start_instances(InstanceIds=StoppedInstances)
```

Lambda role config

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeRegions",
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Corrected and working code below:

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    #region = 'eu-west-1'
    ec2_regions = [region['RegionName'] for region in client.describe_regions()['Regions']]
    for region in ec2_regions:
        client = boto3.client('ec2',region_name=region)
        ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name=region)
        instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['stopped']}])
        StoppedInstances = [instance.id for instance in instances]
        for i in StoppedInstances:
            client.start_instances(InstanceIds=[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try the following.

Instead

```
for i in StoppedInstances:
    startingInstances = ec2.instances.start(i)
```

Can use [start_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.start_instances):

```
client.start_instances(InstanceIds=StoppedInstances)
```

Comment: Hi, Unfortunatelly the error message still occurs `"errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the StartInstances operation: No instances specified",
  "errorType": "ClientError",`

Comment: @tester81 Can you check if `StoppedInstances` contains correct ids of the instances? Maybe its empty?

Comment: Hi, yes, I have just tested it using `print(StoppedInstances), print(ec2_regions)`. and the values are ok, only one thing doesnt work this starting procedure...

Comment: @tester81 Can you update your question with new version of the code and the print outs?

Comment: updated version of the code in the main part of my post.

Comment: @tester81 basic question. Since this is lambda, does its execution role has permissions to act on ec2?

Comment: I think role in IAM is ok, pasted role config in the main window.

Comment: @tester81 looks fine. I don't know what else I can do. I think its something very simple. The only thing that goes into `start_instances` is `StoppedInstances`. Must be something wrong with it. Maybe these instances don't exist there, or they are not in `stopped` state?

Comment: VMs exists and state is stopped, dont have idea what is wrong in that solution, so in your opinion code is ok?

Comment: @tester81 The instances you try to start are in the same region as lambda? I ask because this ` client = boto3.client('ec2')` will be set to same region as lambda. If they are in different, can try specifying `region_name` parameter.

Comment: As You can see in my code, there is a query and the ec2_regions variable, so all regions are put to this variable, then I am using this variable in the loop..., so lambda goes to each region.

Comment: @tester81 `client = boto3.client('ec2')` is not in different regions. only ` ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name=region)` is set to use different region.

Comment: OK, i see, earlier I was using `ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name=region)`. How can I set `client = boto3.client('ec2')` to all regions?

Comment: @tester81 Same, client = boto3.client('ec2',region_name=region). Obviously this also must be in your for loop.

Comment: OK, it works now, I pasted updated code in the main window, but still dont get it why it worked two weeks ago and suddenly stopped working. Anyway, Thanks for you support!!!

Comment: @tester81 Glad to hear it worked out at the end. Also don't know what could have changed.